# SUNDIALS using Python Interface tutorial

Tags: python, dae

I am attempting to solve differential algebraic equations using SUNDIALS with a Python interface. I am having trouble learning to actually use sundials, and cannot seem to find any tutorials online that show some python examples. Would anyone have any links?

Comment: Have you looked at https://scikits-odes.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: More specifically these may be useful https://github.com/bmcage/odes/tree/dc2dcccbc9a2e26743e037ad03699beaa3a1bbc4/ipython_examples

Comment: There's also a SUNDIALS mailing list.

Comment: All very helpful, thanks a lot!